# How can I provide Chromium Snap package permissions to access directories?

Tags: permissions, chromium, jupyter

I installed Chromium from Software Center and and it was fine but it didn't have access to some directories like mounted drives.
Then I read a thread and I uninstalled it and installed the Chromium via APT and then I changed the permissions of the app on software center and I run this command :

```
snap connect chromium:removable-media
```

My problem to access those medias are solved now but still I can get access to some directories like this:

```
/home/name/.jupyter
```

And because of this, jupyter lab can't open automatically on browser.
How do I solve this problem?